# Xbox Home/Guide Button & Win+G no longer working

Tags: pc, controllers

Win+G seems to work when I'm focused on a browser or a game, but the Xbox Guide button does not trigger the Game Bar at all anymore.

It was working fine until I added my Steam games to my Xbox App in Windows 10 then the Xbox Guide button mysteriously stopped working, regardless if on desktop or an actual game.

Like I said, Win+G used to work on the desktop as well, but doesn't anymore.

Any idea what's going on?

The controller is an Xbox One Elite.

Comment: You could try disabling and re-enabling the Game Bar in settings to see if this helps